Determining weights of function by iteratively testing inputs
Say we have a function $F:A^{12} \to B$, where $A$ is some arbitrary set of $5$ elements, and $B$ is some arbitrary set of $12$ elements. Thus we are mapping each ordered $12$-tuple of elements of $A$ to one of the $12$ elements of $B$. We know the function uses a static set of weights to determine its output, in a specific way I'll outline, but otherwise it's a black box. The only way of finding out these weights is by testing the function on various inputs. My question will be how to determine the weights with enough precision to predict the correct output for any input.
The function has one weight for each element of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\} \times A \times B$: an index of the $12$-tuple, a value that might occur at that index, and an element of the codomain. Thus there are $12 \cdot 5 \cdot 12 = 720$ weights in all. Suppose we denote the weight associated with the triple $(i,a_j,b_k)$ as $w_{i,a_j,b_k}$. Then the weights define the output of $F$ as follows:
For a given input $X \in A^{12}$, we compute $12$ sums, one for each element of $B$. The sum associated with each element $b_k \in B$ will be $\sum_{i=1}^{12} w_{i,x_i,b_k}$ (where $x_i \in A$ is the element at the $i$th index of $X$). Then we find the maximum of these $12$ sums, and return the associated element of $B$. I'm assuming that the weights are such that ties are impossible.
The overall problem is to reverse-engineer the weights used, with enough precision that we can correctly predict the output of $F$ for any given input, given that our only means of gathering data is by testing the results on different inputs. Naïvely, we are looking to solve for $720$ variables.
My thoughts
Here's my thinking so far. If we look in $\mathbb{R}^{720}$ for solutions, we will find an inconveniently high-dimensional subspace of solutions that are functionally identical. I believe that if we want the result to be bounded in all dimensions, we want to search $S^{538}$, the unit sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{539}$.
I arrive at this by supposing that we privilege one element of $A$ (say $a_1$) and one element of $B$ (say $b_1$). Instead of representing weights explicitly for these values, we can simply define all other weights in reference to them, so that $w_{i,a_j,b_k}^* = (w_{i,a_j,b_k} - w_{i,a_j,b_1}) - (w_{i,a_1,b_k} - w_{i,a_1,b_1})$. We thus have $12 \cdot 4 + 1 = 49$ weights for each (non-privileged) element of $B$, with the extra $+1$ being a special weight $w_{b_k}^*$ that represents the outcome if $a_1$ were chosen for every question. We multiply this by $|B| - 1 = 11$ to obtain a $539$-dimensional space to search. With the set of weights defined in this way, then a solution set of weights can compute an output for any input $X$ to the quiz in the following way:

For each element $b_k \in B$ other than $b_1$, compute $w_{b_k}^* +\sum_{i=1}^{12} w_{i,x_i,b_k}^*$, treating $w_{i,a_1,b_k}^*$ as $0$ for all $i$ and $b_k$.
If every sum is negative, then $b_1$ is the output. Otherwise, the output is the element of $B$ that corresponds to the maximum sum.

I believe that this gives us a formulation that is identical to the original problem while also being unique up to a scaling factor — hence the restriction to the unit sphere. It's here where I'm stuck. Each new input-output data point will give $11$ linear inequalities, each corresponding to a hyperplane that bounds the solution space. (For instance, if $F(X) = b_2$ for some specific $X$, then we know that $w_{b_2}^* +\sum_{i=1}^{12} w_{i,x_i,b_2}^* > 0$, and that the sum is also greater than the corresponding sum for each of the other elements of $B$.) But given a set of such bounds, obtained from testing various inputs to $F$, I'm not sure how to proceed with determining whether the bounded region corresponds only to the set of solutions that perfectly reproduce $F$, or if not, how to find a test input that would be likely to narrow it down.
Note: The original formulation of this question posed a broader problem, corresponding to $A$ and $B$ of arbitrary (but known) sizes, and tuples of arbitrary (but known) length. In editing the question for clarity, I decided to give the specific case I'm examining, in the hopes that that would make the question more explicit.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As a new user here, I'm not sure exactly what needs to be done. If a human sees this, could you let me know what additional detail is needed (or whether the bot made a mistake, or whether this is the wrong forum, etc.)?

To me, this question is way too verbose. Try to extract the essence, and write it as a short math problem, forgetting all this quiz context.

It's not clear (to me) whether you are speaking of a numerical grade or something more qualitative.  Given that you call this a "Personality Quiz", I'm guessing you mean the latter...so preferring strawberries over blueberries might be a sign of an outgoing personality, or whatever. The point I'm making is that for that sort of test, weighting might be complex...

...In principle, one might have a different personality type for each vector of responses.  In that case, one would need to list all the vectors and see the output.  Or there might be some other mechanism, but it's not clear.  I'm sure you are aware of all the different Voting schemes out there, and this is a similar problem.  Without more detail, I don't think there's much to be said.

Thanks for the feedback. I've rewritten the question in what I hope is a more direct way, as well as narrowing the scope to a more specific case. Does this help?
